# CORS 400 header missing (among other issues)

Tags: javascript, audio, cors, visualizer

This is my first project using javascript (basically forked code from here: https://www.kkhaydarov.com/audio-visualizer/)

I'm trying to build a visualizer that responds to the audio I am hosting.

**Problems:** 
- Getting thrown a CORS 400 error (i'm using https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http:// in my source url)
- Audio is not getting recognized

Here is a link to my project on codepen: https://codepen.io/beewash92/project/editor/ZGWOQr
Code is also stored on my github: https://github.com/beewash/js-audio-visualizer

```
enter code here
```

I've scoured other posts on stackoverflow and across the web, but still running into issues.  You're help is appreciated !

Answer (score -1):

If you try to browse the link in chrome you will get the message as below

`Missing required request header. Must specify one of: origin,x-requested-with`

You will need to define the custom request header as stated above in order for it to work. Refer the api [here](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/) as it clearly stated what you should do beforehand.

You should create a request with the header as follows

```
fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://soundcloud.com/gentttry/10999-1', {
    'headers': {
        'Origin': 'soundcloud.com'
    }
})
.then(res=>res.blob())
.then(blob=>URL.createObjectURL(blob))
.then(audio_src=>{
    // Then init your audio here and assign the url
})
```

Comment: The thing is the link didn't return the audio. You will need to find the actual audio binary link